Problems with wofi cursor and hover styles
I'm trying to make wofi dmenu more mouse-friendly.
I want to show pointer cursor when result item is hovered and add some styles to hovered element with :hover pseudoclass.
But styles from #entry:hover are not applying and there is an error 'cursor' is not a valid property name when cursor: pointer; exists in stylesheet.
Here is the full css file:
@define-color surface0 #313244;
@define-color surface1 #45475a;
@define-color text #cdd6f4;
@define-color border #cba6f7;

* {
  font-family: 'JetBrainsMono Nerd Font';
  font-size: 18px;
}

window {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#inner-box {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px -6px black;
  background-color: @surface0;
}

#text {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  color: @text;
}

#entry {
  background-color: @surface0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#entry:selected, #entry:hover {
  background-color: @surface1;
  outline: 1px solid @border;
}

What am I missing?
